# Jquery Ajax request to Api always fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a totally beginner in Jquery.I make a Ajax request call to my web service which will return me a Json response.But it always return fail() response to my console log,and I dont know why.

**Here is the error response I get in console**

```
Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

**And Here is how I make the Ajax call** I always get the response from fail section

```
$.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",
                JSON.stringify({email:vEmail, password:vPassword}),
                function(response){ // Required Callback Function
                    //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                    console.log(response);
                }, 'json')
                .fail(function(error) {
                    console.log(error) //error always occur here 
                });
```

**Here is the Json response I suppose to get from server**

```
 {
  "error": false,
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "username": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",

  }
}
```

I checked this,is a valid Json from [Jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/),but still cant get response from `success` section.

I read some question state for cross domain issue,but my web service and this front end Javascript project is stay at the same localhost,so will it still cross domain issue?

**So,thing I wanna know is**

1)How can I get the success response in this case?

2)The error response I get above is refer to what?How can I solved it?

I read a lot of question for *Jquery request always failed*,but none of this solved my problem.Hope someone can point me to right direction.Thanks

Comment: if I didnt use `JSON.stringify`,it dont ever have any response on my browser.

Comment: Did you've check your [Network] section on your [console] browser window?

Comment: what should I check in `network` tab?

Comment: In your [network] tab, check your url (e.g http://localhost/abc/v1/log) and check the status error code and preview as well. It may have something to do with the server side